# I am trying to print a table in c++, the code doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I am trying to print the following table. I want it only till 5 rows (As per the homework question).

```
5 10 15 20 25
10 15 20 25 30
15 20 25 30 35
20 25 30 35 40
25 30 35 40 45
```

When I use the following code, there is always an extra entry in the first row (There is 30 after 25, which shouldn't be)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
float i,j, num=0,k=5;
for(j=0; i<5;j++,i+=0.2)
    {num+=5;
    cout<<num<<" ";
    if(j==5)
        {
        cout<<endl;
        j=0;
        k=k+5;
        num=k;}
     }
getch();
}
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: You have *undefined behavior* since you use `i` without initialization. What do you use it for anyway?

Comment: As for your problem, what is the *expected* output? And what is the *actual* output?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It's in the for loop condition `i<5` (not `j<5` as I originally thought)

Comment: I is defined as float. It's a homework question..

Comment: Still doesn't matter, since you use it without initialization.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the first row is - 5 10 15 20 25 30, while it should be 5 10 15 20 25

Comment: Oh, i get it lol.. Facepalm lol.. Just starting to learn.. Thanks

Comment: PS- There was another error.. must initialise j as j=1 while using for loop

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<5; ++i){
      for(size_t j=0; j<5; ++j)
        cout<< (i+j+1)*5 <<"\t";
      cout<<endl;
  }
}
```

What about simpler implementation like this? Unless your real question is something different.

Comment: We have an even simpler version than this.. but the challenge between us, friends was to not use nested loops..

Comment: you forgot return 0;
;)

Comment: @StackDanny According to the C++ Standard the return statement is not required.

Comment: but it's good practise, since your main function is not a void-type, it's an integer type.
And there are cases where it's important what your program returns to the system. Just sayin'. :)

Comment: @StackDanny It is a good practice only for beginners. Experienced programmers do not spend their time to type return 0; :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want it (as you asked for) in one loop:

```
#include <iostream>

#define SIZE 5
int main(){
    int start = 5;
    int increment = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE*SIZE; i++){
        std::cout << start << " ";
        start += 5;
        if (start == increment + SIZE * 5){
            increment += 5;
            start = increment;
            std::cout << '\n';
        }

    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() 
{
    const int N = 5;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < N; j++ ) std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << N * ( i + 1 + j ) << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
 5 10 15 20 25 
10 15 20 25 30 
15 20 25 30 35 
20 25 30 35 40 
25 30 35 40 45
```

As for your code then the variable `i` was not initialized. Also even if `j` is equal to 5 you are printing the current value of `num` in the same line because the if statement follows the output statement

```
cout<<num<<" ";
if(j==5)
```

Your approach can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() 
{
    const int N = 5;

    for ( int i = 0, j = 0, num = 0, k = 0; i < N * N; i++ )
    {
        if ( j == N )
        {
            std::cout << std::endl;
            j = 0;
            k += N;
            num = k;
        }

        num += N;
        std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << num << ' ';
        j++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If for example to initialize the constant `N` to `6` instead of `5`vthen the output will look like

```
 6 12 18 24 30 36 
12 18 24 30 36 42 
18 24 30 36 42 48 
24 30 36 42 48 54 
30 36 42 48 54 60 
36 42 48 54 60 66
```

Also you can combine the both approaches shown above. Here is a demonstrative program that uses only one loop as in your program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() 
{
    const int N = 5;
    const int Value = 10;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N * N; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << Value * ( i / N + 1 + i % N );
        ( i + 1 ) % N == 0 ? std::cout << std::endl : std::cout << ' ';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
10 20 30 40 50
20 30 40 50 60
30 40 50 60 70
40 50 60 70 80
50 60 70 80 90
```

You can set your own values for constant `N` and `Value`.

Comment: #include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 int i,j, num=5,k=5;
 for(j=1, i=0; i<5;j++)
 {
  cout<<num<<" ";
  num+=5;
  if(j==5)
  {
  cout<<endl;
  i+=1;
  j=0;
  k=k+5;
  num=k;}
 }
 getch();
} '

That's what i ended up with.. just been a month since i started..

(Can't we put codes here? New to SO)

Comment: @AzimJaved See my updated post where I showed how your approach can be realized.